# LoadResource() returning hGlobal that I can't interrogate?

Tags: winapi

The following chunk of code results in err1 = 0 (success) and err2 = 6 (invalid handle).

```
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hInst, hrSrc);
    INT err1 = GetLastError();
    UINT gflags = GlobalFlags(hGlobal);
    INT err2 = GetLastError();
```

gflags has a value of 0x8000 which means `GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE`.  I know that the resource exists and if I lock the memory, I get the data in the resource.

My question is why do I get an invalid handle result?  Is the memory returned by LoadResource() a 'special' HGLOBAL that is really not what it seems?

Comment: Just look at the MSDN article for GlobalFlags(), it tells you to only use it for handles returned by GlobalRe/Alloc().  Be careful with error handling, *never* call GetLastError() unless you got an error return from a function.  LoadResource didn't fail, your hGlobal variable isn't NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value returned by `LoadResource` is not really an `HGLOBAL`.

From the `LoadResource` documentation:

> The return type of LoadResource is HGLOBAL for backward compatibility, not because the function returns a handle to a global memory block. Do not pass this handle to the GlobalLock or GlobalFree function. To obtain a pointer to the first byte of the resource data, call the LockResource function; to obtain the size of the resource, call SizeofResource.

All you ever do with the value returned from `LoadResource` is pass it to `LockResource` and `SizeofResource`.

These functions are this way for reasons of backwards compatibility. Older versions of Windows did return real global memory blocks.

Comment: Damn, I was thinking this.  Not sure how I missed that in the docs.  Thanks.